# linear map and the transpose

Tags: dual-spaces, transpose

I am reading Clifford Algebra: An Introduction, by London Mathematical Society. On page 15, I have encountered the statement, which I rephrase as follows.
Let $T$ be a linear mapping from vector space $E$ to $F$. If $\varphi \in F'$ and $x \in E$, let $(T'(\varphi))(x) = \varphi(T(x))$. Then, $T(\varphi) \in E'$, and $T'$ is a linear mapping of $F'$ into $E'$; it is the transposed mapping of $T$.

I can understand the whole statement, but am only not sure whether the phrase "Then, $T(\varphi) \in E'$" is a typo of the book. In my mind, the correct phrase should have been "Then, $T'(\varphi) \in E'$".   By definition, $T(x) \in F$. If not a typo of the book, I can not see why $T(\varphi) \in E'$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, should be $T'(\varphi)\in E'$.

Comment: Thanks. Clifford Algebra: An Introduction is a great book but contains more than one typo.